# Pandas Update Dataframe with other Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv, numpy

I am trying to modify a csv file with data from a second csv file. Both files have a sku column, but they don't match perfectly. Both files also have a price column. I need to update the first file with new prices from the second file where the skus match. It feels simple, but my brain is missing a gear today.

So far I have:

```
oldDf = pandas.read_csv('oldData.csv')
newDf = pandas.read_csv('newData.csv')

oldDf = oldDf.assign(newPrice = oldDf['LIST PRICE'])
oldDf['newPrice'] = newDf['LIST PRICE']

oldDf = oldDf.assign(sku2 = oldDf['SKU'])
oldDf['sku2'] = newDf['SKU']


print(oldDf)
oldDf.to_csv('something.csv')
```

That's not doing anything except adding new columns and showing me things don't line up.

I need something like:

```
if(old['sku'] = new['sku']){
    old['list price'] = new['list price']
}
```

(Please pardon the terribly-syntaxed pseudocode)

Comment: @Chris the second, non-accepted answer might be what I needed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Merge your dataframes on 'SKU'. Something along these lines should work:

```
oldDf = pandas.read_csv('oldData.csv')
newDf = pandas.read_csv('newData.csv')

result = pd.merge(oldDf, newDf, on='SKU')
```

Comment: I had tried something like that earlier. I guess that works if I then just drop/rename all the columns I need to.

Comment: True, you'll need to do renaming.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over `old` like this:

```
for index, row in old.copy().iterrows():
    if old['sku'] == new['sku']:
        old.loc[index, 'list price'] = new.loc[index, 'list price']
```

Edit: Probably we should not update df that we iterate over, but it should work.
The workaround if it does't could be to add `copy()`

Comment: I saw somewhere else on this site that you are not supposed to update dataframes via iterrows

Comment: I believe that in this case it does not matter as long as we don't edit rows that we didn't iterate over yet nor append any rows to 'old' datafrane.